# Do not match opening and closing parenthesis when a character sequence appears in middle

Tags: c#, regex

Got an interesting problem here for everyone to consider:

I am trying to parse and tokenize strings delimited by a `"/"` character but only when not in between parenthesis.

For instance:

```
Root/Branch1/branch2/leaf
```

Should be tokenized as: `"Root"`, `"Branch1"`, `"Branch2"`, `"leaf"`

```
Root/Branch1(subbranch1/subbranch2)/leaf
```

Should be tokenized as: `"Root"`, `"Branch1(subbranch1,subbranch2)"`, `"leaf"`

```
Root(branch1/branch2) text (branch3/branch4) text/Root(branch1/branch2)/Leaf
```

Should be tokenized as: `"Root(branch1/branch2) text(branch3/branch4)"`, `"Root(branch1/branch2)"`, `"leaf"`.

I came up with the following expression which works great for all cases except ONE!

```
([^/()]*\((?<=\().*(?=\))\)[^/()]*)|([^/()]+)
```

The only case where this does not work is the following test condition:

```
Root(branch1/branch2)/SubRoot/SubRoot(branch3/branch4)/Leaf
```

This **should** be tokenized as: `"Root(branch1/branch2)"`, `"SubRoot"`, `"SubRoot(branch3/branch4)"`, `"Leaf"`

The result I get instead consists of only one group that matches the whole line so it is not tokenizing it at all:

```
"Root(branch1/branch2)/SubRoot/SubRoot(branch3/branch4)/Leaf"
```

What is happening here is that because Regex is greedy it is matching the left most opening parenthesis `"("` with the last closing parenthesis `")"` instead of just knowing to stop at its appropriate delimiter.

Any of you Regex gurus out there can help me figure out how to add a small Regex piece to my existing expression to handle this additional case?

```
Root(branch1/branch2) Test (branch3/branch4)/SubRoot/SubRoot(branch5/branch6)/Leaf
```

Should be tokenized into groups as:

```
"Root(branch1/branch2) Test (branch3/branch4)"
"SubRoot"
"SubRoot(branch5/branch6)"
"Leaf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses balanced groups to *capture* each matching item with `Regex.Matches`, ensuring the closing `/` isn't matched when the brackets before it haven't balanced:

```
(?<=^|/)((?<br>\()|(?<-br>\))|[^()])*?(?(br)(?!))(?=$|/)
```

Bizarrely, this seems to perform similarly to [Billy Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665261/billy-moon)'s [much simpler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488707/215380), even though this is overengineered (supporting multiple, possibly nested sets of brackets per token).

---

The following does something similar, but *splits* the string with `Regex.Split` (linebreaks added for clarity):

```
(?<=^(?(brb)(?!))(?:(?<-brb>\()|(?<brb>\))|[^()])*)
/
(?=(?:(?<bra>\()|(?<-bra>\))|[^()])*(?(bra)(?!))$)
```

This matches "any `/` where any brackets between the start of the string and the `/` are balanced, and any bracket between the `/` and the end of the string are balanced".

Note that in the lookbehind, the `brb` captures appear in reverse order from before - this is because a lookbehind apparently works right-to-left. (Thanks to [Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425789/215380) for the answer that taught me this.)

This is *much* slower than the match version, but I wanted to work out how to do it anyway.

Comment: `(?<-BR>\)` looks weird. Is this valid syntax?

Comment: That's supposed to be the "balance" to the first `<BR>` group, e.g. it can only match if there are matched `<BR>` groups, and it removes one from the stack. That said, I don't have immediate access to a compiler and none of the online regex tools I've found seem to support this feature.

Comment: Ah, just found it. Balancing group... This seems to be .NET only feature.

Comment: Hello Rawling, Thanks for your input. This works great for most cases, but does not handle cases like this: "Root(test1/test2) Text (test3/test4)/Branch/Leaf". This needs to be tokenized as "Root(test1/Test2) Text (test3/test4)" , "Branch" , "Leaf". However, the Regex you suggest tokenizes as :"Root(test1/test2) Text(test3", "Branch", "Leaf" with the first token group missing part of the expression string. Any suggestions to fix this case? Thanks!

Comment: @SamA. I've updated the expression - it's still stabbing in the dark without a compiler but I think I see where I went wrong. EDIT: Download Expresso, this semms to work :)

Comment: Thanks @Rawling. I went ahead with you answer and it works for me. and Expresso Rocks! have been using it for a while now to dive a bit in Regex.

Comment: @Rawling do you have any insight into why your regex performs similarly to mine? I wrote mine, expecting it to be much faster, because it is not using costly assertions, which yours seems to have a few of. Are regex engines better now at handling assertions? Could I somehow improve the performance of my regex by another method? (I am going to look into possessive quantifiers). Cheers

Comment: @Billy Honestly, I'm not really sure. Yours is really straightforward, it should be much faster. I wonder if there's a regex profiler tool that could explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> Tokenize(strInput)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  var tokens = new List<string>();
  bool inParen = false;
  foreach(var c in strInput)
  {
      if (inParens)
      {
           if (c == ')')
               inParens = false;
           else
               sb.Append(c);
       }
       else if (c == '(')
               inParens = true;
       else if (c == '/')
            {
                 tokens.Add(sb.ToString());
                 sb.Length = 0;
            }
       else
             sb.Append(c);

  }
  if (sb.Length > 0)
      tokens.Add(sb.ToString());

  return tokens;
}
```

That's untested but it should work.  (and will almost certainly be much faster than the regex)

Comment: Not if you write the regex properly ;=) (IMHO)

Comment: Thanks for your response James. Unfortunately, spec requests this be done in .Net Regex rather than code.

Comment: Hmmm... The "spec" requires?  The only time I've run across an assignment which dictated implementation was homework.

Comment: @robinCTS:IMHO - only if you write the code really badly.  Look at the code. What could a Regex do that could possibly speed it up?  If you wrote the regex optimally, AND compiled it, then you MIGHT be able to match the hand-coded version, but even that would be difficult, as regex just has more inherent overhead. (e.g, the Matches collection is more complex than the simple string list I return) Regexes have their place--I've done a lot in Regex that I'd never try hand-coding--but in this case, where the pattern is rather simple, except for one twist which is difficult in Regex, code is best.

Comment: I have to agree with your general observations there. Even that your solution is faster. Not sure about the "much faster". I'm a bit of a regex optimization freak :)

Comment: @JamesCurran LOL. not in that case. this expression will be used to parse our data for multiple platforms so it was required to be a Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach, trying to avoid costly look-around assertions...

```
/(\(.+?\)|[^\/(]+)+/
```

With some comments...

```
/
(           # group things to be captured
  \(.+?\)   # 1 or more of anything in (escaped) brackets, un-greedily
|           # or ...
  [^\/(]+   # 1 or more, not slash, and not open bracket characters
)+          # repeat until done...
/
```

Comment: I tend to avoid the `.` if at all possible and use the possessive quantifier as much as possible. That would make the pattern `/(\([^)]++\)|[^\/(]++)+/`. In general this speeds up evaluation and helps safeguard against catastrophic backtracking. Unfortunately some regex engines don't do possessive quantifiers.

Comment: You could also use `[^)]` instead of the `.`, although I doubt it would make a difference in backtracking.

Comment: I do it as a safety precaution. I this case you are right in that it won't make any difference. However my way allows me to use the possessive quantifier and _guarantee_ no backtracking will occur.

Comment: Hi Billy. Thanks for your suggestion. I went ahead with @Rawling's suggestion below since it most met my task at hand. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @SamA. Happy to help - it has been an education to me. I have become aware of both possessive quantifiers (which can be emulated with atomic grouping) and balancing group (which I doubt I will even use, as it's language specific, and I try to use widely supported regex only). Thanks

Comment: @BillyMoon - Actually, possessive quantifiers are syntactic sugar for the equivalent atomic group, ie, `.++` is exactly the same as `(?>.+)`. Interestingly enough, some regex engines support atomic groups, but _not_ possessive quantifiers.