# Regular expression for exact word fails when it's consecutive in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm trying to match all the instances of the word "test" exactly in a given text, and I'm using the following regex:

```
/(^|\s)test(\s|\.|$|,|!|\?|;|¿|¡)/gi
```

It works when the text is something like "this is a test. How is the test going? test." However, when you have two or more consecutive "test"'s it does not work.

ie:

```
var regex = /(^|\s)test(\s|\.|$|,|!|\?|;|¿|¡)/gi;
"test test test".match(regex); 
//returns only ["test", "test"], should be ["test", "test", "test"]
```

What can I do to make the regex work with consecutive words?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to know the count of `test` word?

Comment: `/(^|\s)test(?=\s|\.|$|,|!|\?|;|¿|¡)/gi`

Comment: It doesn’t return `["test", "test"]`. It returns `["test ", " test"]` (note the spaces). So, what is your actual expected return value?

Comment: Well you're *not* matching the word `test`, you're matching the word `test` and the character before and the character after it.

Comment: I think you're looking for `/\btest\b/gi`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that \b token !

Comment: A dupe of [whole word match in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript) and [Regex match entire words only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `test` is missing because the space character is consumed when matching the first `test` pattern; You can change the second parenthesis to *look ahead* so it doesn't consume characters:

```js
var regex = /(?:^|\s)test(?=\s|\.|$|,|!|\?|;|¿|¡)/gi;
console.log("test test test".match(regex));
```

Comment: this did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this regex :

```
(?<=\W)test(?=\W)
```

will match any test word preceded and followed by a non word character. This way, it wont match "testtest" for example.

See [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hBfu6t/1)

**Edit :** I am surprised to discover that lookbehind assertions aren't supported in JavaScript apparently ([see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118815/why-are-lookbehind-assertions-not-supported-in-javascript)).
I think in your case the best regex would be the one suggested in the comments : `\btest\b`.

Comment: I just tried this and it's saying invalid regular expression unfortunately.

Comment: I've just edited my answer, apparently lookbehind assertions aren't supported in JS. But you've got one working with the chosen answer anyway, so all good.