# Regular expression to match content between balanced delimeter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given these examples:

```
{{foo}}
{foo{bar}}
{bar}
baz

{quz
{foobar}}
```

the expected output will be:

```
foo
foo{bar}
bar
baz

{quz
foobar}
```

That is to say, search in arbitrary text witch may contains up to one match, and replace the **balanced** delimeter (`{}`) if there are any by using regular expression with the string `replace` method.

```
someStr.replace(/regexp goes here/, match => return match);
```

I know pattern for brackets pair (`{}`) `/\{(.*?)\}/`, (`{{}}`) `/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/`, but don't know how to combine the 0, 1 and 2 occurrences for the brackets into one regular expression.

Also, in order to only match the content without the delimeter, we should use the lookaround assertions https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/1553656

Comment: Why not `foobar}` ?

Comment: Have you tried any regular expression so far?

Comment: @mplungjan guess the meaning is, if no equal amount of delimiters is found on either side, leave value as-is.

Comment: Is it possible to have other characters between braces i.e. `{a{b}}`?

Comment: @CBroe that's it!

Comment: @revo examples updated

Comment: Last question, are they each a single input string or all within a large text?

Comment: Now these are all single examples, to be viewed as one line independent from each other - or do you want to get from that shown input to the output "in one go", one string in, one string out?

Comment: @revo a single input

Comment: @CBroe just for one input witch may have up to one match

Comment: It would be hardly possible even with more featured regex engines to do this. However there should be a solution if no whitespace character is there within braces `{f o o{ba r}}`

Comment: I see you edited your comment from *a large text* to *a single input*. If you mean it I'll go for writing an answer.

Comment: @revo, yep I updated my comment. I think it's ok for a single input and up to only one match for the input.

Comment: Write a parser, not a regex.

Comment: Your input/output examples are still not consistent (or the problem specification is still to vague) - if `{foo{bar}}` results in `foo{bar}`, then `{foobar}}` should be `foobar}`, no? Or is it supposed to check the overall string for matching amount of delimiters, even if nested over multiple "levels", as well ...? Getting way too complex for a simple regex replace here IMHO, too.

Comment: @CBroe yes {foobar}} results in foobar}

Comment: lookbehind support in JavaScript is very limited (Chrome only?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118815/why-are-lookbehind-assertions-not-supported-in-javascript

Comment: @Slai node environment.

Comment: seems pretty easy without RegEx, and pretty complicated with it. Are only RegEx answers acceptable?

Comment: @Slai maybe I make things complicate by accident with regular expression. Of course without regexp are welcome.    For the brackets matching reason I think about regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of those occurrences are within a large text it would be hardly possible to find a working answer even with more featured regex flavors but if they are separated input strings you may have a solution. Count number of braces at beginning of input string and remove closing braces in that number at the end:

```js
var inputStrings = [
    '{{foo}}',
    '{bar}',
    'baz',
    '{quz',
    '{foobar}}',
    '{foo{bar}}'
];

inputStrings.forEach(function(value) {
    var numberOfBracesAtStart = (value.match(/{/gy) || []).length;;
    console.log(value.replace(new RegExp("^\{{" + numberOfBracesAtStart + "}(.*)\}{" + numberOfBracesAtStart + "}$"), '$1'));
})
```

RegEx breakdown:

```
"^\{{" + X + "}(.*)\}{" + X + "}$"
```

- `"^\{{" + X + "}"` Match `{` at beginning `X` times
- `(.*)` Match any thing between
- `"\}{" + X + "}$"` Match `}` at the end `X` times

Such a regex will be cooked for `{{foo}}`:

```
/^\{{2}(.*)\}{2}$/
```

Comment: I think this solve the problem. Also this gives me a clue of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion makes things much easier and shorter:

```js
var trim = s => /^{.*}$/.test(s) ? trim(s.slice(1, -1)) : s;

var a = '{{foo}} {foo{bar}} {bar} baz  {quz {foobar}}'.split(' ');

console.log( a.map(trim).join('\n') );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal really simply is to remove the same amount of opening and closing delimiter characters from each of those lines, then you could also use a simple loop to "count" for how long the first and last characters match { and } respectively, and then simply return the substring of the appropriate length:

```js
var inputStrings = '{{foo}},{foo{bar}},{bar},baz,{quz,{foobar}}'.split(',');

inputStrings.forEach(function(value) {
    var c = 0, l = value.length-1;
    while(value[c]==='{' && value[l-c]==='}') { c++; }
    console.log(value, "->", value.substring(c, l-c+1));
})
```

Might even go with a `for` loop here, that would be even more "literal" use of a tool by it's most basic purpose:

```js
var inputStrings = '{{foo}},{foo{bar}},{bar},baz,{quz,{foobar}}'.split(',');

inputStrings.forEach(function(value) {
  for(var c = 0, l = value.length-1; value[c]==='{' && value[l-c]==='}'; c++) ; // <-!!!
  /* ; at the end is an implicit "NOOP" to make this loop do nothing */
  console.log(value, "->", value.substring(c, l-c+1));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```js
var arr = ["{{foo}}", "{foo{bar}}", "{bar}", "baz", "{quz", "{foobar}}"];
var regx = /^{{([^{}]+)}}|{{?(.*)}?}$/g;
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var match = arr[i].replace(regx, "$1$2");
  res.push(match);
}
console.log(res);
```