# How can I grab words in between consecutive tokens via regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse `:hello::world:` and grab `hello` and `world` individually. Unfortunately the following results in this:

```
const str = ':hello::world:'
const matches = str.match(/\:[^\s]+\:/g)
console.log(matches) // [':hello::world:']
```

Comment: Use `/:[^\s:]+:/g`

Comment: If this is the exact synxat all strings will have, a simple `/\w+/g` will do. It basically means: extract all the adjacent strings consisting of letters and numbers and ignore any other characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex match any string except space that cause match all of string. So you need match any string except `:`

```js
const str = ':hello::world:'
const matches = str.match(/[^:]+/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Note that you can do this work without regex. Just split string by `:` delimiter and remove empty items using `.filter()`

```js
const str = ':hello::world:'
const matches = str.split(':').filter(v=>v!='');
console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your specific use case allows a more simple implementation, but being very strict to your question, you can use this regex:

```
/(?<=:)([^:]+)(?=:)/g
```

It searches for any non colon text that is preceded and followed by a colon.  This way, you can change "str" to "start:hello::brave new world:end" and it still meets your rule in that 'start' and 'end' are excluded because they don't have colons on both sides, and 'brave new world' comes through as a unit.

```js
const str = 'start:hello::brave new world:end';
const matches = str.match(/(?<=:)([^:]+)(?=:)/g);
console.log(matches); // ["hello", "brave new world"]
```

As @Mohammad points out, lookbehind (the first part in parentheses) is a new feature.  So you can tweak my approach to:

```html
const str = 'start:hello::brave new world:end'
const matches = str.match(/:([^:]+)(?=:)/g).map(s => s.slice(1));
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Note that [lookbehind work in ES 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119315/5104748)

Comment: @Mohammad, that's good to know.  The original answer explaining why it took so long was enlightening as well.

Answer (score 1):

You current regex `:[^\s]+:` matches a `:` and then uses a negated character class to match not a whitespace character. That would match  until the end of your example string.

Then it would match a `:` again which is the last `:` in the string resulting in `:hello::world:`

What you could do is to use a capturing group and match not a colon `([^:]+)` between colons and in the result get the first capturing group. Note that you don't have to escape the colon:

```
:([^:]+):
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQIqB0/1)

```js
const regex = /:([^:]+):/g;
const str = `:hello::world:`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```