# Select string after word in JS regex

Tags: regex, make.com

Is there any way to select a string after a specified word?

I found many examples how to select with classic regex:

```
(?<=^License:\W)(\w.*)$
```

...but JS regex is not supporting positive look behind.

I would like to match string after word "License:":

```
License: 1234-YXCMD-12XMDM-XXXCC
```

Is there any solution? I would like to use it on http://integromat.com, which supports only JS regex format.

Comment: Usually, the capturing groups are supported: `License:\s*(\S+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good doc from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Types

So here's something you can do:

```js
let str = "License: 1234-YXCMD-12XMDM-XXXCC"
let regexp = /(?<=License: ).*/
console.log(str.match(regexp)[0]) // get 1234-YXCMD-12XMDM-XXXCC
```

EDIT: This only works in the newest version of Google Chrome as pointed out by @the fourth bird

Comment: `...but JS regex is not supporting positive look behind.` Your pattern uses a positive lookbehind.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's why I have the links there to prove that JS actually support positive look behind

Comment: Lookbehinds are not widely supported in Javascript, see for example [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118815/why-are-lookbehind-assertions-not-supported-in-javascript) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) But as the OP mentioned that it did not work your suggestion will not help solving the problem as it contains a positive lookbehind.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I tried the above regex using Firefox and it did not work. Seems like only the newest version of Chrome supports it. I forgot that the '^' meant at the beginning so I thought they were using a different regexp'