# Javascript RegEx to replace white space between two specific expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove space character from a string **only when** it is bewteen a number and the `G` letter.

Sample text: `XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16 Gb 16 G 2 G ZZZ`

Target result: `XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16Gb 16G 2G ZZZ`

What I have so far is:

```
'XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16 Gb 16 G 2 G ZZZ'.replace(/\d+ gb?/ig, '?')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture a digit and a space (or 1+ spaces) and assert the G at the right.

In the replacement use group 1 `$1` and enable the `/g` flag to replace all occurrences and possibly `/i` for a case insensitive match.

```
(\d) +(?=G)
```

- `(\d)` Capture a single digits
- `+` Match 1+ spaces
- `(?=G)` Positive lookahead, assert a `G` char to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4RKuAz/1)

```js
const regex = /(\d) +(?=G)/g;
console.log("XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16 Gb 16 G 2 G ZZZ".replace(regex, "$1"));
```

Comment: I would use `\s` to match whitespace explicitly - it would made regex more readable I think.

Comment: @MonsieurMerso You could use `\s` but that could also match a newline.

Answer (score 2):

In new version of JS we have **look-ahead** and **look-behind** assertion which means you can do :

```
"XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16 Gb 16 G 2 G ZZZ".replace( /(?<=\d) +(?=G)/g, "" )
```

and outputs:

```
"XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16Gb 16G 2G ZZZ"
```

which says [`(?<=\d) +(?=G)`](https://regex101.com/r/90f7tm/1):

- `(?<=\d)` look-behind to find a single number but do include it in the match
- `+` match one or more space(s)
- `(?=G)` look-ahead to find `G` but do not include it in the match

More

- [Lookahead and lookbehind in modern JS](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind)
- [Why are lookbehind assertions not supported in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119315/4643584)
- [Here you can also see the support for lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) *thanks to @Thefourthbird*

Comment: Here you can also see the support for lookbehind https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by creating Regex groups. Notice the () surrounding both the digit and the "g" and then reusing them in the replace function by indexing them.

```
console.log("XXX YYY AAA 16Gb 16 Gb 16 G 2 G ZZZ".replace(/([\d])\s*(g)/ig, '$1$2'))
```