# What's happening inside regex engine while working with lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, lookbehind

I am working with regex with both PHP and JavaScript. So, I was looking for some good tutorial. From this regex [tutorial](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html) I have found an example for lookbehind that matches a certain 3 digit number only if it is preceded by the the word "USD". There are two different cases where a lookbehind is put both after and before the match.

Here are the regex patterns:

```
\d{3}(?<=USD\d{3}) //after the match
(?<=USD)\d{3} //before the match
```

The example string is:

```
USD100;
```

I grasped the idea but could not figure what is actually going on inside regex engine to complete the task. Can any one explain it to me easily so that I can understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that after the match regex works for you?

Comment: That tutorial is amazing, and [explains everything](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind). What part didn't you understand? For `(?<=USD)\d{3}`, *The lookbehind `(?<=USD)` asserts that at the current position in the string, what precedes is the characters "USD". If the assertion succeeds, the engine matches three digits with `\d{3}`.* and for `\d{3}(?<=USD\d{3})`, *`\d{3}` matches `100`, then the lookbehind `(?<=USD\d{3})` asserts that at that position in the string, what immediately precedes is the characters "USD" then three digits.*.

Comment: lookahead is fine.My problem is with lookbehind.Mainly the internal approach of matching .

Comment: regex engine must have a working procedure for this match.Then how both of them gives the same result where one is after the match and other is before the match?

Comment: There are 2 approaches to implementing look-behind. Although I haven't looked at the code of PCRE in detail, it's likely that it uses the forward-matching method, where the implicit length of the look-behind pattern is studied from the pattern, then it attempts forward matching from (current position - pattern_length). The other approach involves matching backwards, which is what is done in .NET. The look-behind pattern is interpreted from right-to-left and match right-to-left from the current position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below shows how PCRE (and most engines) implements look-behind. Take note of the position of the cursor just before entering the look-behind in each case.

- In the case of `\d{3}(?<=USD\d{3})`, note that the cursor advances 3 positions after matching `\d{3}`, so the look-behind need to look past the 3 digits that it just consumes in order to check for USD in front of them.

  This method makes sure that the numbers are there first, before checking for the prefix.

  ```
  USD100;
  ^
  Attempting to match \d{3}. Fail and bump along.

  USD100;
   ^
  Attempting to match \d{3}. Fail and bump along.

  USD100;
    ^
  Attempting to match \d{3}. Fail and bump along.

  USD100;
     ^
  Attempting to match \d{3}.

  USD100;
        ^
  Matched \d{3}. Attempting to assert (?<=USD\d{3}) (length 6).

  USD100;
  ^     +
  Save current position. Go back 6 characters.
  (Attempt to match USD\d{3} succeeds, positive look-behind succeeds)

  USD100;
        ^
  Back to the saved position and report a match.
  ```
- In the case of `(?<=USD)\d{3}`, note that the cursor is right in front of `100`, so it only needs to look back 3 characters to check that USD is there.

  This method makes sure that the prefix exists first, before matching the numbers.

  ```
  USD100;
  ^
  Attempting to assert (?<=USD) (length 3). Fail length check and bump along.

  USD100;
   ^
  Attempting to assert (?<=USD) (length 3). Fail length check and bump along.

  USD100;
    ^
  Attempting to assert (?<=USD) (length 3). Fail length check and bump along.

  USD100;
     ^
  Attempting to assert (?<=USD) (length 3).

  USD100;
  ^  +
  Save current position. Go back 3 characters.
  (Attempt to match USD succeeds, positive look-behind succeeds)

  USD100;
     ^
  Back to the saved position. Attempting to match \d{3}.

  USD100;
        ^
  Matched \d{3} and report a match.
  ```

Look-behind is not a well-defined operation, so different engines have different implementations and limitations on what is allowed in look-behind.

- .NET implements look-behind by [matching the pattern inside look-behind from right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389560/balancing-groups-in-variable-length-lookbehind/13425789#13425789). This makes it possible to put any construct inside look-behind, but since the tokens in the pattern are read from right-to-left, it is confusing when the pattern contains backreferences.
- Other engines (PCRE included) chooses to match the pattern inside look-behind from left-to-right, by studying the pattern to determine the length of the pattern, and perform a match from the current position minus the length of the pattern. Since not all patterns have a bounded length, most engines reject such patterns to keep the performance reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

[Rexegg explains so](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind):

> `(?<=USD)\d{3}`
>   
>  The lookbehind `(?<=USD)` asserts that at the current
>   position in the string, what precedes is the characters "USD". If the
>   assertion succeeds, the engine matches three digits with `\d{3}`.
>
> `\d{3}(?<=USD\d{3})`
>   `\d{3}` matches 100, then the lookbehind
>   `(?<=USD\d{3})` asserts that at that position in the string, what
>   immediately precedes is the characters "USD" then three digits.

Your question is

> Then how both of them gives the same result where one is after the match and other is before the match?

**The look-arounds are not equal** in each of the example patterns. See

```
\d{3}(?<=USD\d{3})
            ^^^^^
(?<=USD)\d{3}
```

The first one checks if there is `USD` *and* 3 digits right before the current location in string (which is *after* the 3 digits)

The second one checks if there is just `USD` before  the current location in string (which is *before* the 3 digits).

Here is a visualization:

```
       \d{3}(?<=USD\d{3})                 (?<=USD)\d{3}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]
`and`
[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Please let me know if you still have doubts.