# Find the parenthesis pair () within a list of parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, string-comparison, string-matching, ordereddictionary

I have a list of following characters of class Token:

```
3 ( 16 ) 23 ( 24 ( 40 ) 50 ( 66 ) 76 ) 83 ( 88 ( 104 ) 127 )
```

My requirement is to find the pair of parenthesis within this list. In the list, the pairs of parenthesis are: 3,16; 24,40; 50,66; 23,76; 88,104; 83,127.

I'm trying to do this with following approach:

```
public static Dictionary<int,int> GetPair(List<Token> data)
{
     List<Token> token = data;
     var pair = new Dictionary<int, int>();

     int startIndex = -1;
     int currentPosition = -1;
     int finalIndex = -1;

     foreach (var item in token)
     {
         if (item.TokenValue == "(" && (currentPosition == -1 || currentPosition>startIndex) )
         {
             startIndex = item.TokenID;
             currentPosition = startIndex;
         }
         if (item.TokenValue == ")")
         {
             finalIndex = item.TokenID;
             currentPosition = finalIndex;
             pair.Add(startIndex, finalIndex);
         }               
     }   

     return pair;
}

public class Token
{
    public int TokenID { get; set; }
    public string TokenValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm stuck in finding the position of "23 (" because there is another opening parenthesis in the list and it replaces it with "24 (". Kindly help me to fix the logic here??

Comment: @YaelBS this edit isn't a proper edit.

Comment: So why you approved the edit?

Comment: Is either of the solutions works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tested it but this should solve the problem:

```
public static Dictionary<int,int> GetPair(List<Token> data)
{
    var pair = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    var stack = new Stack<Token>();
    foreach (var item in token)
    {
        if (item.TokenValue == "(")
        {
            stack.Push(item);
            continue;
        }

        if (item.TokenValue == ")")
        {
            var starting = stack.Pop();
            pair.Add(starting.TokenId, item.TokenId);
        }
    }

    return pair;
}
```

Comment: No idea, but it does look like you only add the top-level pairs, not the nested ones.

Comment: It worked for nested ones as well. Thanks for the code.

Comment: @iSahilSharma No Problem. I didn't had enough time to test it. Don't forget to mark any post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic interview qustion, you solve it with a `Stack`:

```
public static Dictionary<int,int> GetPair(List<Token> data)
{
    Stack<Token> stacken = new Stack<Token>();
    var pair = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Token temp = new Token();

    foreach (char A in data)
    {
         if (item.TokenValue == "(" )
         {
              stacken.Push(A);
         }

         if (item.TokenValue == ")" )
         {
             if (stacken.Last() == '(')
             {
                  temp = stacken.Pop();
                  pair.Add(temp.TokenID,item.TokenID)
             }
             else
             {
                  stacken.Push(A);
             }
         }
    }

    return pair; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex. Probably it's not too fast like Vera rind solution.

```
string s = "3 ( 16 ) 23 ( 24 ( 40 ) 50 ( 66 ) 76 ) 83 ( 88 ( 104 ) 127 )".Replace(" ", string.Empty);
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(([0-9]+)\([0-9]+\))");
Regex regexNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
Match match = regex.Match(s);
List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
while (match.Success)
{
     var pairNumber = regexNumber.Matches(match.Value);
     if (pairNumber.Count == 2)
     {
         var newPair = new Tuple<int, int>(int.Parse(pairNumber[0].Value), int.Parse(pairNumber[1].Value));
         pairs.Add(newPair);
     }

     // remove last parse
     s = s.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty);
     match = regex.Match(s);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Thanks to **Vera rind** suggestion, I wrote also solution to do that for every (nested level) with NET regex flavour, with regular expression:

```
(?<first>\d+)(?=\s\(\s(?<second>\d+)\s\))|(?<first>\d+)\s(?=\(\s(?:(?:[^()]|(?<Open>\()|(?<Content-Open>\)))+(?(Open)(?!))\s(?<second>\d+)))
```

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cfirst%3E%5Cd%2B)(%3F%3D%5Cs%5C(%5Cs(%3F%3Csecond%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%5C))%7C(%3F%3Cfirst%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs(%3F%3D%5C(%5Cs(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5B%5E()%5D%7C(%3F%3COpen%3E%5C()%7C(%3F%3CContent-Open%3E%5C)))%2B(%3F(Open)(%3F!))%5Cs(%3F%3Csecond%3E%5Cd%2B)))&i=3%20(%2016%20)%2023%20(%2024%20(%2040%20)%2050%20(%2066%20)%2076%20)%2083%20(%2088%20(%20104%20)%20127%20)%203%20(%2016%20(%2033%20(%2024%20)%2012%20)%2023))

it captures pairs of values in groups `first` and `second`. Regex directly match first value of pairs, the second one is captured by group in positive lookahead. It is not the most efficient way, just easier to verified in regex tester if it match properly.

**OLD ANSWER**

In other regex flavours (as far I know) there is no such elegant way to match balanced repatable structures, so for two level of brackets, this solution still works. The stact solution is better in this case, but if whole data is in same format (spacing and max two level paratheses depth) it is also possible with regex:

```
(\d+)\s\(\s(\d+)\s\)|(\d+)(?=\s\(\s(?:\d+\s\(\s\d+\s\)\s)+(\d+))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nM2eN2/1)

Where:

- `(\d+)\s\(\s(\d+)\s\)` - match simple case: namber with following
  number in brackets: `n1 (n2)` , values are captured in groups 1 & 2,
- `(\d+)(?=\s\(\s(?:\d+\s\(\s\d+\s\)\s)+(\d+))` - match number with
  last lonely number in following nested brackets: `n1 ( x1 (x2) y1 (y2) n2 )`, values are captured in groups 3 & 4,

However it will chage list order.

Comment: You can use regex for any depth: `([^()]|(?<open>[(])|(?<close-open>[)]))+(?(open)(?!))` A good explanation is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/2729609) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13425789/2729609). The problem is that the source data it not a string.

Comment: @Verarind but when I try you regex with RegexHero or or RegexStorm, is returns wrong result. And how it should deal with matching `n1 ( x1 (x2) y1 (y2) n2 )` pattern?

Comment: @mcekiera My regex is only a hint not the solution. It uses [balancing group definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx) to match the corresponding parenthesis. This could be used to find the matching pairs. The specified regex doesn't recognize any numbers between the parenthesis - or better the relation between number and parenthesis is lost. The hint is for you in case that you need something like that.

Comment: @Verarind Ok, I understand, this is really interesting and unique NET regex flavour capability. Thank you for comment, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @Verarind I learned how it works and modified my answer, thank you very much once again for hint, it is really valuable lesson for me