# Regex lookback(?). Up to only first tag behind and after identifier

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string containing a simple xml structure:

```
<folder>
 <id=1>
 <id=6>
 <folder>
  <id=2>
  <id=6>
 </folder>
 <folder>
  <id=3>
  <id=5>
 </folder>
</folder>
```

How would I target just the folder containing id=x using regex?

For example, if id=2 I want to return just `<folder><id=2><id=6></folder>`

Comment: yeah you should probably just use linq to xml

Comment: Yes it's C# but thought it was more a regex problem?

Comment: Yeah, when in doubt just default to C#. If they can't use oh swell

Comment: you could use regex but you might just want to deserialize the xml and then you can use linq to do a look up.

Comment: How about searching for how to read and manipulate xml instead of deciding that this is a problem that can be solved with regex? Hint: Regex is a terrible choice for XML.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<folder>\s*(<id=\d+>)*\s*<id=xxx>.*?</folder>
```

Note that your string contains newline characters: **you should unable the "DOTALL" option**. How to enable such option depends on the language you are using.

In the case of C#, it seems that you need to enable [Singleline mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Singleline):

```
Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Example using grep and id=2:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s)<folder>\s*(<id=\d+>)*\s*<id=2>.*?</folder>' a
<folder>
  <id=2>
  <id=6>
 </folder>
```

(Here `(?s)` enables DOTALL.)

Comment: I'm not sure that this works for `id=1` because it should return the whole file/content in the specified case. Maybe the regex has to find the corresponding closing token.

Comment: @Verarind: I do not believe this is a requirement. Especially because it's impossible to deal with an unspecified number of level of nesting with regular expressions.

Comment: Maybe it's impossible in python but .Net knows about [balancing group definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition) what ables you to match the corresponding closing token to an open token.

Comment: Those are "overpowered" regular expressions. Traditional regular expressions have no memory (or, if you prefer, traditional regular expressions can match only regular languages). However, whatever regex dialect you are using, I still believe that using a proper parser would be much easier and much more efficient if you want to deal with nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

`<folder>(?:(?!</?folder>).)*<id=2>(?:(?!</?folder>).|(?<open><folder>)|(?<-open></folder>))*?(?(open)(?!))</folder>`

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/CrbGtr)

**Explanation**

We start with the requested tag: `<folder>`

Now something that is not `<folder>` and `</folder>`: `(?:(?!</?folder>).)*`

Next what we're looking for: `<id=2>`

And than there is comming something `.*` till the end token: `</folder>`

The problem is that *something* can contain an opening and closing token. That has to be captured. Best way of doing this is using [balancing group definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition). Having this we can match until we find the closing token. `.*` has to be the BGD for your tokens: `(?:(?!</?folder>).|(?<open><folder>)|(?<-open></folder>))*?(?(open)(?!))`

A good introduction into BGD is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/2729609) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425789/2729609)