# Match a sequence of two distinct characters where the disparity in count is not greater than 3

Tags: regex

### The problem

You are provided two things: A bag filled with balls of two types, labeled as A and B, and a two-pan balance scale. Each ball is sequentially taken out and placed on the corresponding pan. The game is won if all the balls are taken from the bag while ensuring that there is never a difference greater than 3 in the number of balls on the scale at any point.

Given a sequence of `A`s and `B`s, is it possible to determine whether it is a winning game using regex alone?

### Credits

This question derives from *[Regex can't have diference greater than 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77592383)*, which was closed due to the OP's undesire to clarify the problem. Regardless, the problem was interesting; I was encouraged to post this question thanks to [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/u/4145280).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the DFA.

Denote states by numbers.
Starting state is 1.
All except 8 are accepting states.

[image: DFA generated with https://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/]

Transitions:

```
(1,A)->2    (1,B)->5
(2,A)->3    (2,B)->1
(3,A)->4    (3,B)->2
(4,A)->8    (4,B)->3
(5,A)->1    (5,B)->6
(6,A)->5    (6,B)->7
(7,A)->6    (7,B)->8
(8,A)->8    (8,B)->8
```

Giving:

```
1 = e + 2B + 5A
2 = 1A + 3B
3 = 2A + 4B
4 = 3A
5 = 1B + 6A
6 = 5B + 7A
7 = 6B
8 = 4A + 7B + 8A + 8B
```

Then applying Arden's Theorem to solve for `1+2+3+4+5+6+7` gives:

```
^(
  ((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*
|(((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*A(A(AB)*B)*)
|(((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*A(A(AB)*B)*A(AB)*)
|(((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*A(A(AB)*B)*A(AB)*A)
|(((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*B(B(BA)*A)*)
|(((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*B(B(BA)*A)*B(BA)*)
|(((A(A(AB)*B)*B)|(B(B(BA)*A)*A))*B(B(BA)*A)*B(BA)*B)
)$
```

which becomes a bit more legible after simplification:

```
^
(
 (A(A(AB)*B)*B)
|(B(B(BA)*A)*A)
)*
(
 (A(A(AB)*B)*(A(AB)*A?)?)
|(B(B(BA)*A)*(B(BA)*B?)?)
)?
$
```

Adapting the test from the other answer: https://regex101.com/r/DsYrzp/5

Answer (score 3):

> [...] is it possible to determine whether it is a winning game using regex alone?

**Yes**, with .NET's balancing groups.

### Step 1: Check at the end

If you already know what [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)/[balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799) are and [how to read .NET regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36047988), please continue.

To check that the difference in number is not greater than 3 at all positions, first we need to do the same at one position: the very end of the input.

First, let's collect all the balls into two groups, `a` and `b`:

```
^(?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))+$
```

For no reason at all, let's return to the start to finish the check there instead:

```
^
(?=
  (?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))+$
)
```

Now we have two numbers represented by the stacks, `a` and `b`. We need to know which one is greater, but we can only add (capture) or subtract (uncapture); we can't compare them directly.

This means a drop of math is needed. Assuming `a` is greater than or equals to `b`, we can easily see that:

`a` - `m` >= `b` - `m` (1)

Since the numbers cannot be negative:

`a` >= `b` >= `min(a, b)` >= 0 (2)

From (1) and (2):

`a` - `min(a, b)` >= `b` - `min(a, b)` >= 0

In a more regex-like explanation, if we subtract `min(a, b)` from both, whichever group still has at least one stack is the greater, or they are equal. This check is now much easier, since we have [conditional groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

```
(?(a) ┌───┐ | ┌───────────────────┐ )
      a > b   (?(b) ┌───┐ | ┌───┐ )
                    a < b   a = b
```

For comparison, here's the ternary-operator equivalent

`a` `?` `a > b` `:` ( `b` `?` `b > a` `:` `a = b` )

Let's go ahead and do that; this does not need backtracking, so we use an atomic group:

```
(?>(?:(?<-a>)(?<-b>).)*)
(?(a)
  # a > b
|
  # a <= b
)
```

In the first branch, `a` - `b` is guaranteed to be greater than or equals to 1. However, we need to compare it against 3.

For `a` - `b` > 3, we can apply the same principle: subtract by 3, then check with a conditional:

```
(?<-a>){3}
(?(a) ┌───────┐ | ┌────────┐ )
      a - b > 3   a - b <= 3
```

But `a` - `b` might *not* be greater than 3, so the subtraction must be optional and only enforced when it is possible to do so:

```
(?> (?: ┌────────┐ ) ? )
        (?<-a>){3} 
(?(a) ┌─────────┐ | ┌───────┐ )
      a - b > 3 ?   a - b = 3
```

A new problem arises: How to differentiate `a` - `b` > 3 and 3 > `a` - `b` > 0? Simple: Just introduce a new group:

```
(?> (?: ┌────────┐ ┌─────┐ ) ?  )
        (?<-a>){3} (?<a3>)
(?(a) ┌────────────────────────────────┐ | ┌───────┐ )
      (?(a3) ┌───────┐ | ┌───────────┐ )   a - b = 3
             a - b > 3   3 > a - b > 0
```

Since we only need to discard the match when `a` - `b` > 3, the construct can be simplified as:

```
(?> (?: ┌────────┐ ┌─────┐ ) ?  )
        (?<-a>){3} (?<a3>)
(?(a) ┌───────────┐ )
      (?(a3) ┌──┐ )
             (?!)  # Always fail
```

Apply the same trick to the other branch, we have:

```
(?(a)
  (?>(?:(?<-a>){3}(?<a3>))?)
  (?(a)(?(a3)(?!)))
|
  (?>(?:(?<-b>){3}(?<b3>))?)
  (?(b)(?(b3)(?!)))
)
```

...which leads us to the final regex:

```
^
(?=(?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))+$)
(?>(?:(?<-a>)(?<-b>).)*)
(?(a)
  (?>(?:(?<-a>){3}(?<a3>))?)(?(a)(?(a3)(?!)))
|
  (?>(?:(?<-b>){3}(?<b3>))?)(?(b)(?(b3)(?!)))
)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DsYrzp/3) ([full line version](https://regex101.com/r/DsYrzp/1)).

### Step 2: Check at all positions.

"All" implies a loop. Therefore, the template will look something like this:

```
^
(?:
  # ...
)+
$
```

At step 1, we captured all characters before returning to the start to verify. However, we wouldn't be able to do that if we were to check at all positions. This is where lookarounds come into play.

```
^
(?:
  (?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))
  (?<=
    # Verification...
  )
)+
$
```

First, let's try to make the regex we got from step 1 check at the actual end. After collecting all characters into the stacks, we don't have anything else to match, so we need a lookaround, or more precisely, a lookbehind. Lookbehinds match backwards, so the content needs to be inverted:

```
^
(?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))+
(?<=
  (?(a)
    (?(a)(?(a3)(?!)))(?>(?:(?<-a>){3}(?<a3>))?)
  |
    (?(b)(?(b3)(?!)))(?>(?:(?<-b>){3}(?<b3>))?)
  )
  (?>(?:(?<-a>)(?<-b>).)*)
)
$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DsYrzp/4).

Insert this to the template above, we see that it... [does *not* fully work](https://regex101.com/r/2nfoMX/1):

```
^
(?:
  (?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))
  (?<=
    (?(a)
      (?(a)(?(a3)(?!)))(?>(?:(?<-a>){3}(?<a3>))?)
    |
      (?(b)(?(b3)(?!)))(?>(?:(?<-b>){3}(?<b3>))?)
    )
    (?>(?:(?<-a>)(?<-b>).)*)
  )
)+
$
```

`AAABBBBAAABBBBAAAABBB`, for example, doesn't match while it is supposed to. This is due to the lookbehind: It modifies the stack on the run.

To fix this, we need to copy the stacks by adding a bunch of zero-width patterns and groups... or a small trick:

`(?<=` `)` can also be written as `(?<!(?<!` `))`

If I recall correctly, I learned this trick from an answer by [@MartinEnder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/8478) at Code Golf. The only difference is that negative lookarounds never modify the stacks or affect the pattern at large: it must fail for the engine to continue matching.

And that was it:

```
^
(?:
  (?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))
  (?<!(?<!
    (?(a)
      (?(a)(?(a3)(?!)))(?>(?:(?<-a>){3}(?<a3>))?)
    |
      (?(b)(?(b3)(?!)))(?>(?:(?<-b>){3}(?<b3>))?)
    )
    (?>(?:(?<-a>)(?<-b>).)*)
  ))
)+
$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2nfoMX/2).

### Inevitable conclusion

This is purely a theoretical question. A simple for loop is much easier to write and much *much* easier to read/explain. As with [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378) [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405), while regex might be able to give a solution, there is most often at least one better way.

Regardless, I'm willing to be enlightened if there is a PCRE solution. `:)`