# How does atomic group inside a positive lookbehind work?

Tags: .net, regex, lookbehind

I don't understand why the regex `(?<=i:(?>\D*))\d` [does not match](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3di%3a%28%3f%3e%5cD*%29%29%5cd&i=i%3a%3e1) the string `i:>1`.

The way I undertand it:

- at index 0: the lookbehind `i` won't match
- at index 1: the lookbehind `i:` won't match
- at index 2: the lookbehind `i:(?>\D*)` will match `i:` but the `\d` after the lookbehind won't match `>`
- at index 3: the lookbehind `i:(?>\D*)` will match `i:>` and the `\d` after the lookbehind will match `1` -> the regex is satisfied

Comment: I know that it works if I replace the atomic group `(?>\D*)` with a `\D*`, but I want to know what is happening with the atomic group. This is a simplified version of a more complex regex that I had an issue with.

Comment: The problem here is that the lookbehind is implemented in such a way that the `(?>\D*)` is executed before `i:`, and `i:` is matched with `\D*`, and as it is inside an atomic group, no backtracking is possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "lookbehind is implemented in such a way that the ‍‍`(?>\D*)` is executed before `i:`", thanks, but why have they done that? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: The only link I can find is [one of Kobi's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425789/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Regular Expressions Cookbook: Detailed Solutions in Eight Programming Languages](https://books.google.pl/books?id=yY_EsWFMj-QC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=right-to-left+regex+.net+implementation&source=bl&ots=dFI9jP87_A&sig=3ITjd-QZU8ow5SA7viYZ_QAEgdI&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDvdL05LzYAhUrDJoKHa6BDd8Q6AEIYDAG#v=onepage&q=right-to-left%20regex%20.net%20implementation&f=false):

> .NET allows you to use anything inside lookbehind, and it will actually apply the regular expression from right to left. **Both the regular expression inside the lookbehind and the subject text are scanned from right to left.**

The `(?<=i:(?>\D*))\d` pattern does not match the `1` in `i:>1` because the atomic group `(?>\D*)` prevents any backtracking into its pattern. The `i:` (actually, `:` and then `i` gets matched) is matched with `\D*`, and then there no way to re-match `i:` as the atomic group does not allow backtracking.

You can also see that [`(?<=i:(?>[^:\d]*))\d` will match `1` in `i:>1`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3di%3a%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%3a%5cd%5d*%29%29%5cd&i=i%3a%3e1) because here, `[^:\d]*` matches any char but `:` and digits, and thus only comes up to `i:` and `i:` is still there to be matched.